# Import Cassandra 1.2 data to Cassandra 2.0

Tags: import, cassandra

I have taken a snapshot of my data from a 1 node cass 1.2 server (using the nodetool snapshot command). Is it possible for me to import this data into a 1 node cassandra 2.0 server?

My initial thinking is that perhaps I need to use the SStable2json tool, but is there an easier way, meaning is there a way I can just import from the snapshot I have.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you create the keyspace and column family exactly as you did on your 1.2 server, you can just put your snapshot in / and restart Cassandra.  Alternatively you can run 'nodetool refresh' if you don't want to restart Cassandra.

Now Cassandra 2.0 will work with your 1.2 data.  You should then run 'nodetool upgradesstables' to rewrite the SSTables in 2.0 format.